# Update all WooCommerce products if "sale_price" is greater than "price"

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am trying to update ***wp_postmeta*** table for all products sale price.

I'm struggling with how to work this, due to both fields being **`meta_key`** / **`meta_value`** pairs in this ***wp_postmeta*** table.

How can I write a query that will update all `'_sale_price' = 0 WHERE '_sale_price' > '_price'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different approach with a custom function that should do the same job. You will have to use this function **just one time**, and then remove it after the job is done (at first site load, the process will depend on number of products you have).

Here is the code:

```
function update_products_sale_price(){

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );

    // getting all products
    $products = get_posts( $args );

    // Going through all products
    foreach ( $products as $key => $value ) {

        // the product ID
        $product_id = $value->ID;

        // Getting the product sale price
        $sale_price = get_post_meta($product_id, '_sale_price', true);

        // if product sale price is not defined we give to the variable a 0 value
        if (empty($sale_price))
            $sale_price = 0;

        // Getting the product sale price
        $price = get_post_meta($product_id, '_price', true);

        // udate sale_price to 0 if sale price is bigger than price
        if ($sale_price > $price)
            update_post_meta($product_id, '_sale_price', '0');
    }
}

// Here the function we will do the job.
update_products_sale_price();
```

You can also embed the code function in a hook…

*This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme or theme*

**This code is tested and fully functional**

---

References:

- [WordPress Code Reference - Function get_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)
- [WordPress Code Reference - Function update_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/)

Comment: `update_post_meta('product_id', '_sale_price', '0');` Should this line read: `update_post_meta('$product_id', '_sale_price', '0');` with the $product_id variable?

Comment: @MikeF Oh Yes sure, a small mistake… I correct this. thanks. Did this code work for you once corrected this?

Comment: It did, yes. I've made a slight adjustment to it though. If the sale price is greater than the price, then I've set it to run a delete query on that meta_key/meta_value pair on the corresponding post_id column. That way woocommerce won't show it. Thank you for your help, it's greatly appreciated.